# Is dynamic memory comparable to global variables?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

In a **linked list** we declare `node` like this:

```
struct node
{
    int data;          // Data part
    struct node* next; // pointer to next node

    node(int key)
    {
        data = key;
        next = NULL;
    } 
};
```

Our insert function looks something like this

```
void insert(int key)
{
    struct node* go = head; // Head is global.
    while(go != NULL) 
    { 
        go = go -> next; 
    }
    go -> next = new node(key);
}
```

If the function `insert` is actually returning `void`, then how is it able to make changes to the linked list?

Does memory allocated by operator `new` (from the free store) act like a global variable?

Comment: No, it is not correct, there's no `Struct` in C++. `struct node* next` is not necessary, `node* next` would be enough. And `insert` is using the global `head` variable, which is how it's "able to make changes".

Comment: You came up with two completely different questions. What you're asking is totally unclear.

Comment: I think, the while condition should be `(go->next != NULL)`. But that was not the question.

Comment: @LogicStuff I know that I am not able to communicate please let me know how can I correct.

Comment: @LogicStuff Main question is does memory located by new is like that of global vaiable i.e can be modified from any function without actually returning anything

Comment: Note that **a function does not have to return anything** to modify global variables.

Comment: @szczurcio Yes,I know about that.Thanks for telling about node* next.I didn't know about that.My main question is that is memory located by new act like global variable ?

Comment: In which aspect? 1. You need a pointer to access allocated memory. That pointer might not be global. 2. You can manage a lifetime of dynamically allocated object with `new`/`delete`, as opposed to global variable. Learn the fundamentals before comparing the two.

Comment: What should I read ? Linked list or memory allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

new is not like global variable. In C++, Global Variable (assuming you not talking about global pointer) is allocated before your application entry point which is "main" is called and deallocate when your application is shutdown.

new in other hand allocate new memory in when it called and deallocate when you call delete

```
MyClass* c = new MyClass(); // Allocate
// ..
delete c; // Deallocate, MyClass c is deleted
```

So if you make some object with new, and never delete it. It will always exist but you may lost the pointer to the data allocated and causing memory leak.

Comment: Suppose I have memory allocated by new.Can I modify the "next" or "data" from any function if I have access to the pointer returned by new.

Comment: if it public then yes you can

Comment: Thanks I am 90% convinced.For rest 10%  should read text book once again